# Python How to split a string when find the first numeric char

Tags: string, python-2.7, split

This is my string: 
"Somestring8/9/0"

I need to get something like this: 
['Somestring','8/9/0']

The moment I find a numeric char, I need to split the string to get:
'8/9/0'

This my code:

```
stringSample = "GigabitEthernet8/9/0"
print re.findall(r'(\w+?)(\d+)', stringSample)[0]
('GigabitEthernet', '8')
```

But I'm getting this result
What am I doing wrong?

I appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second regex group accepts only digits. Allow it to include forward slashes too.

```
stringSample = "GigabitEthernet8/9/0"
print re.findall(r'(\w+?)([\d/]+)', stringSample)[0]
# ('GigabitEthernet', '8/9/0')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Using the [re.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) method to split your string in two, passing the `maxsplit` parameter

```
re.split('(\w+?)([\d/]+)', stringSample, 1)
```

Comment: With this solution I'm getting this result: ['', 'Somestring', '8/9/0', '']. In the list are 4 elements, the first and the last are nulls, Why is that?